# Start a new activity on click listview using onclicklistener

Tags: android, json

**I need help to do a simple click in a listview to start a new activity using onclicklistener.I am using JSON to parse the data.Below is my code
   **

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private CategoryAdapter adapter;
        private CategoriesBean cb;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            cb = callCategory();

            List<Category> catList = new ArrayList<Category>();

            adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, cb.getCategoryBn());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            MenuInflater mif = getMenuInflater();
            mif.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.share:
                return true;

            case R.id.settings:
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppSettings.class);
                startActivity(in);

            case R.id.feedback:
                return true;

            case R.id.about:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        }

        private CategoriesBean callCategory() {
            CategoriesBean cb = new CategoriesBean();

            NetworkClass netClass = NetworkClass.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
            cb = netClass.callCategory();

            return cb;
        }

        private void showData() {
            DbAdapter1 helper = DbAdapter1.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
            Cursor cur = helper.fetchQuery("select * from jokes");
        }

        public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            Context context;
            List<Category> catList = new ArrayList<Category>();

            TextView categoryName;
            TextView categoryCount;

            public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> items) {
                this.context = context;
                this.catList = items;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return catList.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return catList.get(position);
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
            {

                if(convertView==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater vi =    (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
                    convertView=vi.inflate(R.layout.inflate_categoryrow,null);
                }

                categoryName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryname);
                categoryName.setText(catList.get(position).getCatName());
                categoryCount=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.categorycount);
                categoryCount.setText(catList.get(position).getCatCount());






                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

> something should be within this onClick method to get the position of the list and start a new activity

```
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {



                        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CategoryDetail.class);


                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });

                return convertView;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can directly use the position variable to get the position right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the `position` to the other activity:

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CategoryDetail.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putInt("Position", position); //position is one of the method arguments
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

To retrieve this info within the other activity set this line on the `onCreate` method:

```
int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Position");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [onItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) for your listview, Like this:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your position variable is final you can use it in your onClick block:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  //In case you need the object at the position
  Object objectAtPosition = getItem(position);

  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putInt("YOUR_POSITION_EXTRA", position);
  Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CategoryDetail.class);
  i.putExtras(bundle);

  startActivity(i);

}
```

Don't see any problem there. If this is not the solution could you try to be more specific what your problem is?